# I need a BI software to manage my company and the company branches

Tags: windows, business-intelligence

I work for a bank with have a lot of branches/agencies.
We're willing to implements a new BI solution in our company.

The data from all branches is in the same database. 
I need a BI solution that allows me to create web reports templates and return the data according to the branch.

For instance, if the manager of the branch XYZ access the BI, he can see all the reports and views but only the info of your branch. He cannot see the data from the other branches.

The company have + 800 branches so it's impossible to create each report 800 times.

Keep in mind, the company uses Microsoft solutions as Windows Server, SQL Server, ASP.NET sites and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com) provides an end to end [Business Intelligence Solution](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard).

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard Platform]

- *Need a BI solution that allows me to create web reports templates and return the data according to the branch*: Yes. Can be implemented using [user based filters](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-designer/compose-dashboard/configuring-user-based-filter/using-expression-fields)
- *The company have + 800 branches so it's impossible to create each report 800 times* - You only need one report/Dashboard for all the users/branches. The Dashboard is treated as a template and data is filtered based on group/user.
- *Company uses Microsoft solutions as Windows Server, SQL Server, ASP.NET sites* - The Dashboard Server is implemented using ASP.NET MVC and the solution connects to SQL Server. There is also a [Dashboard SDK](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-sdk/overview) for customization such as embedding into custom applications.

The solution is available as a [self hosted](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/dashboard) application or [cloud hosted](https://www.syncfusion.io/) solution.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. One more questiom. How the login works? It's possible to use the Active Directory to manage the user logins ??

Comment: @Guilherme Batista Yes. User login can be configured with Active Directory https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-server/site-settings/active-directory

Comment: Great! I will present your solution to the project stakeholders